# Angular SEO одна страница

Tags: angularjs

Итак, есть веб-приложение

Оно написано на AngularJS.

Мне нужно индексировать две страницы. Главную и FAQ.

Мои варианты:

- отлавливать user agent ботов и выдавать эти две страницы в html без js вообще, только для поисковиков;
- закончились варианты.

Как все-таки сделать правильно?
Как отловить всех ботов через Nginx?

Comment: Настраивайте апач (или что у Вас там). Проверяйте useragent и отдавайте статически сформированную страницу. Единственное, что нужно помнить, - это [_escaped_fragment](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification?hl=ru).

Comment: http://chat.highfeed.ru/login - форма дергается вверх-вниз.

SRWare Iron Версия 25.0.1400.0 (185000)

Разрешение 1920х1080

Comment: @smackmychi, постоянно или при открытии страницы?

Comment: @exec
Постоянно. Туда-сюда.

Comment: @smackmychi, баг принят к исправлению.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зачем придумывать что-то, за что вас потом забанят (*гуглим клоакинг*), если есть рекомендации от поисковиков:

- Яндекс: [Индексирование AJAX-сайтов](https://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/robot-workings/ajax-indexing.xml)
- Google: [Часто задаваемые вопросы по AJAX](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174993), [Сайты, использующие AJAX](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/81766), [Спецификация (eng.)](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification)

Для ленивых. Если ваш FAQ открывается по адресу `http://www.example.com/#!faq`, то поисковик попытается открыть `http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=faq`, где он будет ожидать версию для себя.